# Как Apache Spark будет параллельно(или не) брать и обрабатывать данные?

Tags: apache, apache-spark

Я решил попытаться разобраться с **Apache Spark**, и в ходе знакомства с документацией и примерами у меня возник следующий вопрос:

Как спарк будет параллельно(или нет) брать и обрабатывать данные?

1. В документации существует куча примеров с **sc.textFile(“example.txt”)**, но нет примеров с parallelize, получается все это будет обрабатываться в 1 потоке(для каждого spark-submit)?
2. Есть примеры с **HBase, HDFS,** скажите, а как будут браться данные из **hdfs**, по 1 куску или сразу пачкой(и будут как-то распределятся и суммироваться)? и как всё это будет обрабатываться? параллельно(распределено различными воркерами)? 
   Что будет в случае использования **hbase**? а в случае с **JDBC(POSTGRES)**? Как распределять задания в таком случае?

В дополнение:
Как отправлять данные в spark? я вижу только spark-submit, а существуют ли другие способы и как получить только результат, а не весь мусор?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Spark в принципе предназначен для того, чтобы обрабатывать данные распределённо и параллельно. В связи с этим можно сказать, что он *всегда* старается запускать обработку в параллели, если не сказано другого. Запускать приложение с использованием Spark можно либо с использованием скрипта `spark-submit`, либо как обычное Java-приложение, используя Spark как библиотеку. В любом случае при запуске необходимо указание параметра `master`, который определяет где и как будет выполнен код.

Основные варианты для параметра `master` следующие:

- `local[*]` - запуск кода локально на пользовательской машине, а не на кластере. Если в квадратных скобочках звёздочка - для работы используются все доступные ядра ЦПУ (т.е. происходит работа в параллели). Вместо звёздочки можно указать число - сколько ядер использовать. Если написать просто `local` - работать будет аналогично `local[1]`, т.е. в один поток без распараллеливания.
- `yarn` - запуск кода с использованием YARN-кластера. Без предварительного конфигурирования кластера и Spark'а запускается один контейнер для выполнения кода драйвера (процесс, контролирующий выполнение задачи) и два для экзекьюторов, на которых непосредственно обрабатываются данные (т.е. тоже в параллели). Также при запуске `spark-submit` можно указать параметр `--num-executors`, где можно точно прописать необходимое количество экзекьюторов.

Теперь же о том, что такое `sc.textFile(...)` и чем отличается `sc.parallelize(...)`:

- `sc.textFile(...)` - чтение данных из файла (локального или лежащего в HDFS). Принимает в качестве параметра соответствующее имя файла (или папки - в этом случае на вход будут отправлены все файлы внутри указанной папки).
- `sc.parallelize(...)` просто принимает на вход коллекцию объектов и преобразует её в RDD для последующей обработки.

Эти методы никак не влияют на параллелизм. Однако, есть другие методы, которые действительно могут на это повлиять - `repartition` и `coalesce` (подробнее здесь: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations).

Answer (score -1):

Ну я как бы только изучаю spark, но всё же посоветовал бы разобраться в том как устроен HDFS, YARN. Предположим что файл который храниться в HDFS разбит на 10 частей. И для каждой части, на каждой машине будет создан контейнер куда зальётся рабочий код спарка. Тоесть грубо говоря будет файл обрабатывать в 10 потоках и на разных машинах. 
Не скажу точно, но я думаю что метод parallelize в продакшине не используется, и он скорей всего для тестирования, и наглядных примеров.